# How to add with SourceTree a new directory to a local repo previously cloned from BitBucket?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I created a repo in Bitbucket, then cloned it locally. [This tut here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/copy-your-repository-and-add-files-729980492.html) explain how to add which is straightforward. My issue is how to a new directory. I dropped the new dir in the project but SourceTree is not showing the newly added directory. But, if I add a new file it shows it in SourceTree's file status and you can commit and the push it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You want to push an empty directory to the repository, am I getting you right?

Comment: No, the directory has files and directories in it.

Comment: Ok, I can add the new dir if I clone it as `https` but if I try to clone as `ssh` then I get an error: `This is not a valid source path/URL`.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/clone-a-repository-223217891.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, after many hours I found what was causing this issue. It was a .git  file. `rm -rf .git` should remove any .git related.